# Using De Morgan law

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Using DeMorgan's Law, write an expression for the complement of F if

$$A.\ \ F(w,x,y,z) = xz'(x'yz + x) + y(w'z + x')$$

$$B. \ \ F(x,y,z) = xz' (xy + xz)+ xy'(wz + y)$$

My Answer is

A. $$((x'z)+(x+y'+z'+x'))((y'+(w+z')+x)),$$

B.
 $$(x'+z)(x'+z')(x'+z')(x'+y')+(w'+z'(y')).$$

I'm not 100% sure if my answer is correct. I just took all the ANDs, negated them and made them ORs and vice-versa.

Comment: What about $(w′z+x′)$ ?

Comment: You have "converted" it into : $(w+z′)+x$. You started with one AND and one OR and eneded with two ORs...

Answer (score 0):

Work the complement in one step at a time:

A.

$$\big( xz'(x'yz + x) + y(w'z + x') \big)'=$$

$$\big( xz'(x'yz + x) \big)' \big( y(w'z + x') \big)'=$$

$$\big( x'+z+(x'yz + x)' \big) \big( y'+ (w'z + x')' \big)=$$

$$\big( x'+z+(x'yz)'x' \big) \big( y'+ (w'z)'x \big)=$$

$$\big( x'+z+(x+y'+z')x' \big) \big( y'+ (w+z')x \big)$$

B.

$$\big( xz' (xy + xz)+ xy'(wz + y) \big)'=$$

$$\big( xz' (xy + xz) \big)'  \big(xy'(wz + y) \big)'=$$

$$\big( (xz')' +(xy + xz)' \big)  \big(x'+y+(wz + y)' \big)=$$

$$\big( (x'+z) +(xy)'(xz)' \big)  \big(x'+y+(wz)'y' \big)=$$

$$\big( (x'+z) +(x'+y')(x'+z') \big)  \big(x'+y+(w'+z')y' \big)$$

Answer (score 0):

Use parenthesis rather than order of operations, and just change it 1 character at a time.  $v$ becomes $v'$ and vice versa, $+$ becomes $\cdot$ and vice versa:

$$\begin{array} {}
( & x & \cdot & z' & \cdot & ( & ( & x' & \cdot & y & \cdot & z & ) & + & x & ) & ) & ) & + & ( & y & \cdot &  ( & ( &w' &\cdot& z & ) & + & x' & ) & )\\
%
\\
%
( & x' & + & z & + & ( & ( & x & + & y' & + & z' & ) & \cdot & x' & ) & ) & ) & \cdot & ( & y' & + & ( & ( & w & + & z & ) & \cdot & x & ) & )\\
\end{array}$$